# groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: COUNTER for class:

Tags: bash, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to run a groovy script in Jenkins but I am getting this error: `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: COUNTER for class`

Here's the script:

```
def runAzureMockExecution(Map m = [:]) {

    Map args = [
            ENDPOINT : "",
            action : "",
            vmCount : "",
            numSubscriptionId : "",
    ]

    args << m
    println(args)

    def ENDPOINT = args.ENDPOINT
    def action = args.action
    def vmCount = args.vmCount
    def numSubscriptionId = args.numSubscriptionId

    sh("""
        arr=();
        COUNTER=0
        while [  $COUNTER -lt $numSubscriptionId ]; do
        suffix=$RANDOM
        arr+=($suffix" ")
        let COUNTER=COUNTER+1
        done
    """)
}


runAzureMockExecution(
                        ENDPOINT: "https://sample-url.com",
                        action: "ADD",
                        vmCount: 1,
                        numSubscriptionId: 5
                )
```

Can anyone help me here? I also tried running the same script in online compilers but got the same error as above.

Answer (score 0):

Groovy is trying to interpolate the Variables in your `sh` block, since you don't have any variables defined as `COUNTER` it's failing. Simply escape the `COUNTER` and other variables like below.

```
sh("""
    arr=();
    COUNTER=0
    while [  \$COUNTER -lt $numSubscriptionId ]; do
    suffix=\$RANDOM
    arr+=(\$suffix" ")
    let COUNTER=COUNTER+1
    done
""")
```

Another option is to pass everything as environment variables and avoid string interpolation by surrounding the `sh` script with single quotes.

Comment: Now I am getting this error:
`groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: jdoodle.sh() is applicable for argument types: (String) values`